# When using try/catch/finally, with error inputmismatch exception, How do I correctly implement a finally block, WITHOUT getting an error

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

AND YES I have looked at simialr quesions and NO I cannot find an answer to my question...If you have a question about my question or code. PLEASE ASK.

```
do{
         try {
            System.out.print ("Volume of a cone... V = 1/3(3.14)r^2(h)");
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Input Radius: ");
            radius = keyBoard.nextDouble ();
            System.out.print ("Input Height: ");
            height = keyBoard.nextDouble ();
         //math
            volume = 0.333 * pie * radius * radius * height;
            System.out.printf ("Volume =   " + volume);
         }//end try
         catch (Exception Error){
            System.out.println ("You Entered the Wrong Data.");
         }
         finally {

            System.out.println ();

            System.out.print ("Do you want to try again?");
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Input '1' to go again OR any other key to End.: ");
            counter = keyBoard.nextInt ();
         }//end finally

      }while (counter == 1);
```

Comment: What is the question and does it even compile.Immediately downvoted :P

Comment: THIS is the output I Get WITH the ERROR
Volume of a cone... V = 1/3(3.14)r^2(h)
Input Radius: s
You Entered the Wrong Data.

Do you want to try again?
Input '1' to go again OR any other key to End.: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at volumeConeC.main(volumeConeC.java:43)

Comment: This complies but once I input a 'Wrong Data' it immediately gives my exception in thread...

Comment: Bomb proof input is kinda hard.  What level are you?  You might want to ask your instructor what you can do here, they might give you some code if the input verification isn't part of the assignment.

Comment: I don't have an instructor to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem:**

```
counter = keyBoard.nextInt ();
```

After you input a string to the `nextDouble` it will consume the `newLine` character by the `nextInt()` and will result to `InputMismatchException` because `newLine` is not an Int.

**solution:**

consume the `newLine` character in your catch block before asking for input from the user

**sample:**

```
         catch (Exception Error){
            System.out.println ("You Entered the Wrong Data.");
            keyBoard.nextLine();
         }
```

EDIT:

```
boolean tryAgain = false;
    do{
         try {

             if(tryAgain)
             {
                System.out.println ();

                System.out.print ("Do you want to try again?");
                System.out.println ();
                System.out.print ("Input '1' to go again OR any other key to End.: ");
                counter = keyBoard.nextInt ();
                tryAgain = false;
             }

            System.out.print ("Volume of a cone... V = 1/3(3.14)r^2(h)");
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.print ("Input Radius: ");
            radius = keyBoard.nextDouble ();
            System.out.print ("Input Height: ");
            height = keyBoard.nextDouble ();
         //math
            volume = 0.333 * pie * radius * radius * height;
            System.out.printf ("Volume =   " + volume);
            tryAgain = true;
         }//end try
         catch (Exception Error){
            System.out.println ("You Entered the Wrong Data.");
            keyBoard.nextLine();
            tryAgain = true;
         }

      }while (counter == 1);
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I seriously appreciate it.

Comment: @user2755775 click the check mark on this post to mark as answered. You are welcome and happy coding.

Comment: Rod_Algonquin...I have another somewhat unrelated question if you can answer it for me....Why is it that if I place the end of finally after the while the alignment of the blocks get messed up?

Comment: @user2755775 you can not put it outside the while statement. avoid doing that.

Comment: OP - did this solution work for you?  I have some real doubts about it; in fact, I believe it's wrong.  But you have given it the "green tick" which indicates it's OK.  You've got this running then, or do you need more help?

Comment: @user2755775 Many people recommend not using the nextInt/nextDouble and similar for this reason. Consider nextLine instead followed with Integer.parseInt instead.

Comment: @DavidWallace I actually tried his code and input an **s** just like he did in the comment.

Comment: yes this works and I realize now that a finally wasn't even needed but I don't understand why it can't be placed outside the while

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Kudos for actually testing your answer. But a newline character doesn't make `nextInt` throw an `InputMismatchException`. It's the `s` that causes the problem.  So this might work, but not for the reason you gave. It may also give problems later if the user types something other than a number when they're asked whether they want to try again. So this really isn't a very robust solution, and the explanation is very misleading.  I'd hate to think that the "green tick" that you pressured the OP into applying is going to discourage some other respondent from posting a better answer.

Comment: @David Wallace I see what you are saying about what is the problem. I didn't quite know how to word my question. For what I needed this worked but to make it better would be to replace counter.keyBoard.next() with nextLine??

Comment: @DavidWallace he can always change hes code to add flags and still preserving the nextLine().

Comment: @user2755775 you can always use flag see EDIT above.

Comment: That works well but it automatically restarts if everything is entered in correctly the first time around.

Comment: @user2755775 just add `tryAgain = true;` after the `System.out.printf ("Volume =   " + volume);`

Comment: You cannot put the finally outside the while loop because, like the catch, the finally is part of the try block. It's there to make sure a certain set of code always gets executed even if an error occured. Putting the finally outside the while would be like taking an else and putting it outside the loop.